# how to search for '$(TARGET) in awk?

Tags: awk

In a Makefile, I'm trying to automatically replace `$(TARGET)` with `$(OBJ1) $(OBJ2)` when the line contains the pattern `all:`.
suppose the Makefile is just

```
all: $(TARGET)
```

when I do `awk '/all:/{gsub("$(TARGET)","$(OBJ1) $(OBJ2)"); print}' Makefile`, it gives me

```
all: $(TARGET)
```

meaning the pattern search failed. I tried putting `\` in front of $ in vain. How should I do it? (I also tried gawk)

---

ADD : (after find a get-around, found another problem..)

This does the trick. It's using regular expresss `.` for `$` place.
But this is a get-around and there should be a real solution to search for `$` character. Anyway I put it here so that someone can get help.

```
awk '/all:/{sub(".(TARGET)","$(OBJ1) $(OBJ2)");print}' Makefile
```

But the output is like this :

```
all: obj obj2 taxi_output $$(OBJ1) $(OBJ2))
```

There are two dollar signs before OBJ1 and two ')' characters at the end. How should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sed:

```
sed '/^all:/{s/$(TARGET)/$(OBJ1) $(OBJ2)/g}' Makefile
```

Also you can use the `-i` flag to overwrite the file.

These work with awk:

```
awk '/all:/{gsub("[$][(]TARGET[)]","$(OBJ1) $(OBJ2)"); print}' Makefile

awk '/all:/{gsub("\\$\\(TARGET\\)","$(OBJ1) $(OBJ2)"); print}' Makefile

awk '/all:/{gsub(/\$\(TARGET\)/,"$(OBJ1) $(OBJ2)"); print}' Makefile
```